# Differences between a Statistician and a Data Analyst in industry

Tags: machine-learning, regression

What is the Difference in the job of a Statistician and a Data Analyst In Industry? My take is that although both analyse data, a Statistician deals with the more theoretical aspects of data such as using mathematics to analyse data and to create mathematical models of data. So their work is more towards the mathematics side of things. Whereas the job of a Data Analyst deals more with the programming and side of things and their job is more practical in nature and they focus more on the implementation side.

Im more of a theoretical person and im more mathematically orientated and i wanted to do a job that involves lots of math, so is a statistician job more suited for me rather than a Data Analyst?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A major difference is the job market: you'll find a lot of job ads for data analysts/scientists, very few for theoretical statisticians. In most sectors (there are some exceptions, in banking for example), companies are interested in applying existing models to their data because this is what can increase their profits.

Devising new theoretical models is more on the research side of innovation. Most "pure research" job opportunities are in academia, although some big companies have research departments as well.

Comment: Then what about Statistical Research? Im planning to work for the Government as a Statistics Researcher.  Such as this  https://careers.pageuppeople.com/688/cwlive/en/job/532027/senior-executiveexecutive

Comment: As you can see this job requires some statistics skills and some applied skills ("data processing", "apply computer packages"). It's important to understand that there's no strict  distinction between "statistician" and "data scientist", it's a continuum between very theoretical and very applied. Even a (good) data scientist job requires a fair amount of theoretical background nowadays, and conversely a statistician job requires at least a bit of skills in data processing.